# cg-busy div is not disappearing -- angular 1.5 -- angular-busy

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular-busy for my application . Its a simple div attached to the dom with cg-busy attribute like below  --

```
<div cg-busy="myFavoritesCtrl.myPromise">
</div>
```

The controller invokes an api and assigns the promise to the controller instance . Below is the controller instance in typescript -

```
module MyFavorites.Module {

    export class MyFavoritesController {
        static $inject = ['$log', 'projectService'];
        myFavoriteProjects: any;
        myPromise: any = null;

   constructor(private $log: angular.ILogService,
            private projectService: Nucleus.Services.IProjectService) {
            this.activate();
        }

       private activate() {
            this.myPromise = this.projectService.getFavorites().then((response) => {
                this.myFavoriteProjects = response;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

What happens is the cg-busy tag appears . Once the api conmples the `cg-busy` overlay appears again and it never goes off . There are no extra api calls --

[image]

The network tab also shows there are no other requests going out --

[image]

can somebody tell me what is happening . I have used it numerous times before it  worked . One more note: I am using `angular 1.5.0` with typescript .

Comment: i think you must Returning a value from your  then callback.

Comment: Its just a plain promise . So the `.then (function(){})` would always return a value